# DELPHI + idHTTP + POST()

Tags: delphi, post, try-except

delphi xe7, win 7 x64

how correct make idHTTP.POST() ?

i mean if i try simple

```
    HTTP.post(URL, params);
    if HTTP.ResponseCode=302 then
    begin
```

i just stuck here and cant get revive text etc..

this code work

```
try
    HTTP.post(URL, params);
  except
    if HTTP.ResponseCode=302 then
    begin
```

but i dont like this "try except"..

how i can correctly make this POST without try,except ?

Answer (score 2):

302 is an HTTP redirect to a new URL.  If the `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` property is False (which is the default), `TIdHTTP` treats it like any other error, raising an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception by default.  So, either set `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` to True and let `TIdHTTP` redirect automatically (you can use the `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` event to detect individual redirects), or else disable the exception if you want to handle the 302 yourself.

1. If you are using a version of Indy 10.6 from the past 2 years, you can enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, eg:

   ```
   HTTP.HTTPOptions := HTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
   HTTP.Post(URL, params);
   if HTTP.ResponseCode=302 then
   ```
2. if you are using an older version then you will have to call `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` directly instead of `TIdHTTP.Post()` so you can specify 302 in the `AIgnoreReplies` parameter. The catch is that you must pass the `params` data as a `TStream`, eg:

   ```
   type
     TIdHTTPAccess = class(TIdHTTP)
     end;

   //HTTP.Post(URL, params);
   ParamStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     WriteStringToStream(ParamStream, TIdHTTPAccess(HTTP).SetRequestParams(params));
     ParamStream.Position := 0;
     TIdHTTPAccess(HTTP).DoRequest('POST', URL, ParamStream, nil, [302]);
   finally
     ParamStream.Free;
   end;
   if HTTP.ResponseCode=302 then
   ```